# No sound after update to ubuntu 17.10

Tags: sound, 17.10, pulseaudio, alsa, soundcard

After installing Ubuntu 17.10 I don't have sound and I don't see my devices on sound devices list (there is only one - Digital Output (S/PDIF)):

[image: sound devices]

I have proper installed sound drivers, and I hear sound when I execute:

```
aplay -D sysdefault /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Side_Right.wav
```

`lspci -nnk | grep -A3 -Fe '[0403]'`:

```
00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) HD Audio Controller [8086:293e] (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] G33/P35 Neo [1462:7360]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
--
01:00.1 Audio device [0403]: NVIDIA Corporation Device [10de:0fba] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Device [1458:36c5]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
```

`aplay -l`:

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: Intel [HDA Intel], device 0: ALC888 Analog [ALC888 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: Intel [HDA Intel], device 1: ALC888 Digital [ALC888 Digital]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

`pactl list short sinks` (there is only one device):

```
0   alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.iec958-stereo  module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 44100Hz   IDLE
```

`pactl list cards`:

```
Card #0
    Name: alsa_card.pci-0000_01_00.1
    Driver: module-alsa-card.c
    Owner Module: 6
    Properties:
        alsa.card = "1"
        alsa.card_name = "HDA NVidia"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HDA NVidia at 0xfe97c000 irq 17"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:01:00.1"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card1"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "10de"
        device.vendor.name = "NVIDIA Corporation"
        device.product.id = "0fba"
        device.string = "1"
        device.description = "HDA NVidia"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
    Profiles:
        output:hdmi-stereo: Digital Stereo (HDMI) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 5400, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 300, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround71: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 300, available: no)
        output:hdmi-stereo-extra1: Digital Stereo (HDMI 2) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 5200, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround-extra1: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 2) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 100, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround71-extra1: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 2) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 100, available: no)
        output:hdmi-stereo-extra2: Digital Stereo (HDMI 3) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 5200, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround-extra2: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 3) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 100, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround71-extra2: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 3) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 100, available: no)
        output:hdmi-stereo-extra3: Digital Stereo (HDMI 4) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 5200, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround-extra3: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 4) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 100, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround71-extra3: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 4) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 100, available: no)
        off: Off (sinks: 0, sources: 0, priority: 0, available: yes)
    Active Profile: off
    Ports:
        hdmi-output-0: HDMI / DisplayPort (priority: 5900, latency offset: 0 usec, not available)
            Properties:
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
            Part of profile(s): output:hdmi-stereo, output:hdmi-surround, output:hdmi-surround71
        hdmi-output-1: HDMI / DisplayPort 2 (priority: 5800, latency offset: 0 usec, not available)
            Properties:
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
            Part of profile(s): output:hdmi-stereo-extra1, output:hdmi-surround-extra1, output:hdmi-surround71-extra1
        hdmi-output-2: HDMI / DisplayPort 3 (priority: 5700, latency offset: 0 usec, not available)
            Properties:
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
            Part of profile(s): output:hdmi-stereo-extra2, output:hdmi-surround-extra2, output:hdmi-surround71-extra2
        hdmi-output-3: HDMI / DisplayPort 4 (priority: 5600, latency offset: 0 usec, not available)
            Properties:
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
            Part of profile(s): output:hdmi-stereo-extra3, output:hdmi-surround-extra3, output:hdmi-surround71-extra3

Card #1
    Name: alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1b.0
    Driver: module-alsa-card.c
    Owner Module: 7
    Properties:
        alsa.card = "0"
        alsa.card_name = "HDA Intel"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HDA Intel at 0xfcff8000 irq 29"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:1b.0"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "8086"
        device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
        device.product.id = "293e"
        device.product.name = "82801I (ICH9 Family) HD Audio Controller (G33/P35 Neo)"
        device.form_factor = "internal"
        device.string = "0"
        device.description = "Built-in Audio"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
    Profiles:
        input:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Input (sinks: 0, sources: 1, priority: 60, available: yes)
        output:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 6000, available: no)
        output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Duplex (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 6060, available: yes)
        output:analog-surround-21: Analog Surround 2.1 Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 800, available: no)
        output:analog-surround-21+input:analog-stereo: Analog Surround 2.1 Output + Analog Stereo Input (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 860, available: yes)
        output:analog-surround-40: Analog Surround 4.0 Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 700, available: no)
        output:analog-surround-40+input:analog-stereo: Analog Surround 4.0 Output + Analog Stereo Input (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 760, available: yes)
        output:analog-surround-41: Analog Surround 4.1 Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 800, available: no)
        output:analog-surround-41+input:analog-stereo: Analog Surround 4.1 Output + Analog Stereo Input (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 860, available: yes)
        output:analog-surround-50: Analog Surround 5.0 Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 700, available: no)
        output:analog-surround-50+input:analog-stereo: Analog Surround 5.0 Output + Analog Stereo Input (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 760, available: yes)
        output:analog-surround-51: Analog Surround 5.1 Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 800, available: no)
        output:analog-surround-51+input:analog-stereo: Analog Surround 5.1 Output + Analog Stereo Input (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 860, available: yes)
        output:analog-surround-71: Analog Surround 7.1 Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 700, available: no)
        output:analog-surround-71+input:analog-stereo: Analog Surround 7.1 Output + Analog Stereo Input (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 760, available: yes)
        output:iec958-stereo: Digital Stereo (IEC958) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 5500, available: yes)
        output:iec958-stereo+input:analog-stereo: Digital Stereo (IEC958) Output + Analog Stereo Input (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 5560, available: yes)
        off: Off (sinks: 0, sources: 0, priority: 0, available: yes)
    Active Profile: output:iec958-stereo+input:analog-stereo
    Ports:
        analog-input-front-mic: Front Microphone (priority: 8500, latency offset: 0 usec, not available)
            Properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone"
            Part of profile(s): input:analog-stereo, output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo, output:analog-surround-21+input:analog-stereo, output:analog-surround-40+input:analog-stereo, output:analog-surround-41+input:analog-stereo, output:analog-surround-50+input:analog-stereo, output:analog-surround-51+input:analog-stereo, output:analog-surround-71+input:analog-stereo, output:iec958-stereo+input:analog-stereo
        analog-input-rear-mic: Rear Microphone (priority: 8200, latency offset: 0 usec, available)
            Properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone"
            Part of profile(s): input:analog-stereo, output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo, output:analog-surround-21+input:analog-stereo, output:analog-surround-40+input:analog-stereo, output:analog-surround-41+input:analog-stereo, output:analog-surround-50+input:analog-stereo, output:analog-surround-51+input:analog-stereo, output:analog-surround-71+input:analog-stereo, output:iec958-stereo+input:analog-stereo
        analog-input-linein: Line In (priority: 8100, latency offset: 0 usec, not available)
            Part of profile(s): input:analog-stereo, output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo, output:analog-surround-21+input:analog-stereo, output:analog-surround-40+input:analog-stereo, output:analog-surround-41+input:analog-stereo, output:analog-surround-50+input:analog-stereo, output:analog-surround-51+input:analog-stereo, output:analog-surround-71+input:analog-stereo, output:iec958-stereo+input:analog-stereo
        analog-output-lineout: Line Out (priority: 9900, latency offset: 0 usec, not available)
            Part of profile(s): output:analog-stereo, output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo, output:analog-surround-21, output:analog-surround-21+input:analog-stereo, output:analog-surround-40, output:analog-surround-40+input:analog-stereo, output:analog-surround-41, output:analog-surround-41+input:analog-stereo, output:analog-surround-50, output:analog-surround-50+input:analog-stereo, output:analog-surround-51, output:analog-surround-51+input:analog-stereo, output:analog-surround-71, output:analog-surround-71+input:analog-stereo
        analog-output-headphones: Headphones (priority: 9000, latency offset: 0 usec, not available)
            Properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-headphones"
            Part of profile(s): output:analog-stereo, output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo
        iec958-stereo-output: Digital Output (S/PDIF) (priority: 0, latency offset: 0 usec)
            Part of profile(s): output:iec958-stereo, output:iec958-stereo+input:analog-stereo
```

`pactl list sinks`:

```
Sink #0
    State: IDLE
    Name: alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.iec958-stereo
    Description: Built-in Audio Digital Stereo (IEC958)
    Driver: module-alsa-card.c
    Sample Specification: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
    Channel Map: front-left,front-right
    Owner Module: 7
    Mute: no
    Volume: front-left: 52663 /  80% / -5,70 dB,   front-right: 52663 /  80% / -5,70 dB
            balance 0,00
    Base Volume: 65536 / 100% / 0,00 dB
    Monitor Source: alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.iec958-stereo.monitor
    Latency: 371332 usec, configured 371519 usec
    Flags: HARDWARE HW_MUTE_CTRL DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY SET_FORMATS 
    Properties:
        alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
        device.api = "alsa"
        device.class = "sound"
        alsa.class = "generic"
        alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
        alsa.name = "ALC888 Digital"
        alsa.id = "ALC888 Digital"
        alsa.subdevice = "0"
        alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
        alsa.device = "1"
        alsa.card = "0"
        alsa.card_name = "HDA Intel"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HDA Intel at 0xfcff8000 irq 29"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:1b.0"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "8086"
        device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
        device.product.id = "293e"
        device.product.name = "82801I (ICH9 Family) HD Audio Controller (G33/P35 Neo)"
        device.form_factor = "internal"
        device.string = "iec958:0"
        device.buffering.buffer_size = "65536"
        device.buffering.fragment_size = "32768"
        device.access_mode = "mmap+timer"
        device.profile.name = "iec958-stereo"
        device.profile.description = "Digital Stereo (IEC958)"
        device.description = "Built-in Audio Digital Stereo (IEC958)"
        alsa.mixer_name = "Realtek ALC888"
        alsa.components = "HDA:10ec0888,14627360,00100001"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
    Ports:
        iec958-stereo-output: Digital Output (S/PDIF) (priority: 0)
    Active Port: iec958-stereo-output
    Formats:
        pcm
```

And I see my devices in `alsamixer`:

[image: alsamixer]

and in `gnome-alsamixer` I can see 'lost' devices:

[image: gnome-alsamixer]
[image: gnome-alsamixer2]

What can I do to fix my problem?

Comment: @david-foerster thanks for response!

I have added what you suggested. Everything was muted, but nothing changed when I turned  sound on.

Comment: If you solved your problem yourself, please [answer your own question](/help/self-answer) and accept your answer. Don’t put the answer in your question or the comments! Send me a message in the comments if you want my up-vote. :-)

Comment: I have already tried removing this directory, but after your comment I verified, that I don't have this directory at all. So I created empty `~/.pulse` and restarted pulseaudio and I could hear sound!

But after a while I went to settings and I saw only 1 devices (Digital Audio) that was unselected. When I clicked it I lost sound and I cannot unselect it again because it is only one device. Trick with removing and recreating ~/.pulse is not working now.

Any new idea?

Comment: Ok, I am able to do it again, but it is working for a while only (e.g. to moment  when I go to system setting menu and then only one devices (Digital Audio) is selected). When I have sound I can see different (but still only one) sink:
`0 alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo module-alsa-card.c s16le 2ch 44100Hz RUNNING`

Comment: @DavidFoerster do you have any new idea?

Answer (score 0):

Same problem, on ubuntu 16.04.....  after clicking on launcher.parameters.sound and on 'output' I clicked something wrong, and impossible to go back....

You can try lo install  the appli 'pavucontrol' native from pulseaudio, which must be also installed..  With 'pavucontrol' (named 'contrôle de volume' in French), after 'output peripheric', access 'configuration' and here you can select the good analogic input.. 
I don't understand why it works.....
good luck!

Comment: Thanks, your workaround works! It is annoying but I don't see nothing better :)

But still I cannot do anything in "Sound" menu in main Ubuntu settings window. Whenever I click there I lost my sound. But then your trick helps me :)

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with previous versions of Ubuntu and Mint.  If you open alsamixer as root ie. sudo alsamixer and right arrow along to the end you will probably find "auto-mute" - enabled. Press enter and change it to disabled.  This was the 'simple' fix I spent HOURS trying to find... doesn't work unless you open as root.

Good luck.