# I cannot open system settings in ubuntu 17.10

Tags: system-settings

When I chose settings from taskbar menu nothings happened. I have been working a while ago, last think that I did was removing ~/.pulse directory and `run pulseaudio -k` and `pulseaudio --start` (from this thred - [No sound after update to ubuntu 17.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1007188/no-sound-after-update-to-ubuntu-17-10)).

I can see error in logs when I click setting button (`journalctl /usr/bin/gnome-shell -f -o cat`):

```
JS ERROR: TypeError: app is null
Indicator<._onSettingsClicked@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/status/system.js:336:9
wrapper@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82:22
Indicator<._createSubMenu/<@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/status/system.js:266:57
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reinstall the Gnome Control Center using :

```
sudo apt install --reinstall gnome-control-center
```

Comment: Perfect!  Worked on 18.04